# Google Analytics not showing iphone device

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics

I have a `Google analytics` account with android already set,i need to integrate it with iPhone. I have done the coding part. I am using the same `tracking ID` which I used in android. Currently only android device and android os is displayed in google account. How should I add iOS and iDevices in Google analytics account? Code is working fine, I have seen the changes in "Events"
Whether I need to do anything else...
Added SDK, libraries
Code follows

```
    //Google Analytics:
- (void)startGoogleAnalyticsTracking {
    @try {
        [GAI sharedInstance].debug = NO;

        [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 120;
        [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
        self.googleAnalyticsTracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"******"];
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception:%@",exception);
    }
}

- (void)sendGoogleAnalyticsStartup {
    @try {
        [self.googleAnalyticsTracker sendEventWithCategory:@"iphone" withAction:nil withLabel:@"Tracking Starts" withValue:nil];
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception=%@",exception);
    }
}

- (void)stopGoogleAnalyticsTracking {
    @try {
        [self.googleAnalyticsTracker sendEventWithCategory:@"iphone" withAction:nil withLabel:@"Tracking Suspended /Stopped" withValue:nil];
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception=%@",exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which SDK version of Google Analytics are you using on both Android and iPhone ?
Do you know which type of account are you using ? (Web / Mobile)

Comment: i am using mobile,i have downloaded the library from google analeptics account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also working with Google Analytics in these days.
And I noticed that it takes approximately 24 hours to see the result.
However you can also test it in Real-Time menu whether or not the app sends the data.

[image]

Comment: `Real-Time` depends on `dispatchInterval`, in the given sample code it will be 120seconds